# Search button doesn't scale in with the rest of search bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm new to the whole CSS coding and sometimes I get stuck. I followed an online tutorial on how to make a search bar that is animated so it looks pleasing. I'm doing a website for my school project and I'm almost finished just adding few bits here and there. It's about technology from the beginning of the 20th century to our present day.

```css
.search-pos {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 330px;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-55%, -55%);
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-btn {
  color: black;
  float: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 80%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-pos">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
    <a class="search-btn" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried changing the padding, positioning or even the height but nothing seems to work. I think I need to add another line of code but I'm unsure what it would be.

This what happens:

[Image / Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZHQl.jpg)

As you can witness the button doesn't stay inside the bar itself like it should.

Comment: could you explain what is wrong and how it is suppose to look like? Also do you need to use floats and can't use flex?

Comment: please share your header HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i understand you need to change your css a little bit.

```
.search-pos {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 330px;
height:40px;
  position: relative;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-55%, -55%);
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
display:flex;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-btn {
  color: black;
  float: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 80%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

Let me know, if this solution helps you.

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot. Turns out I just needed to add display: flex; and now I just need to play around with positioning. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like Dejan.S I did not get what is the problem. 
Be carreful you put a top in a relative class `.search-pos`, it doesnt work !

I copy your code in CodePen and I think the problem comes from in a other class or maybe in your `$search.pos` class

https://codepen.io/auxb/pen/WNQjjyp?editors=1100

(I replace the font icon by a img but is the same)

Tell me if this code satisfied you !

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code that handles the hover after the specified elements:

```
.search-box:hover>.search-txt
```

should come after

```
.search-txt
```

also

```
.search-box:hover>.search-btn
```

should come after

```
.search-btn
```

Hope that helps in ensuring the hover effects work as expected.

Also there is no `CSS property` such as `float: center;`